# How to set header on Apache Camel 3.X.X route?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing, apache-camel

I am doing integration testing on the Camel route.

The Camel route:

```
from("direct:abc")
  .routeId("abc-route")
  .process(MyProcessor())
  .toD("direct:xyz")
```

As this route is getting tested into isolation, I need to set headers in the test; previously, they arrived from another route. How can I do it?

Simplified test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MyRouteTest {

  @Autowired
  lateinit var camelContext: CamelContext

  @Produce(uri = "direct:abc")
  lateinit var template: ProducerTemplate

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:xyz")
  lateinit var destEndpoint: MockEndpoint

  @Test
  fun `should test route`() {
    template.sendBody("")
  }
}
```

I have tried doing `camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext::class.java)` but still cannot get to the route and forcibly modify it.

Comment: The [ProducerTemplate](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.1/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html) has a couple of methods available to send a body with headers. i.e. `template.sendBodyAndHeaders(...)` or for a single header `template.sendBodyAndHeader(...)`. You could also weave the route and add a `.setHeader("headerName", constant(value))` or instead of a constant value use `.setHeader("headerName", simple(expression))` to add a simple-language evaluated value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though already answered in the comments, I think the question is worth to have an answer.

The [`ProducerTemplate` interface](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/f649d2f9d893c7b7004b69da518c69a9c6c2be9c/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.java) has lots of different methods to send a Camel Exchange to a Camel endpoint.

There are methods to just send a message body, a body with one or multiple headers or a body with one or multiple Exchange properties.

**There is also a [fluent interface](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/producertemplate.html#_fluent_interface)** that can be used to customize the Exchange in a **nice, descriptive way**.

Example from the Camel Docs:

```
Integer result = FluentProducerTemplate.on(context)
    .withHeader("key-1", "value-1")
    .withHeader("key-2", "value-2")
    .withBody("Hello")
    .to("direct:inout")
    .request(Integer.class);
```

Comment: When using a producer template routeID is not possible. 
I am having an issue where my from in route depends on the headers passed by the producer template or . Is there any suggestions on how to implement the same.

Comment: The routeId is a static identifier of the route (used for logging etc). If you don't set one, Camel simply uses route-1, route-2 or similar. The routeId is set on route creation and cannot be changed. You can't use a dynamic value that is different for every message as routeId. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I have asked my question in here. Can you check the same.  Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70960478/calling-a-camel-route-using-producer-template