# Calling a camel route using Producer Template

Tags: apache-camel, spring-batch, spring-camel

My use case is based on the rest controller input I need to fetch or move files from different source system to destination system.

Route :-

```
@Component
public class MoveFile extends RouteBuilder {
@override
public void configure() throws Exception {

from("file:tmp/${header.inPath}")
    .to("file:/tmp${header.outPath}?fileName=${header.fileName}")
    .setBody().constant("File - ${header.inPath}/${header.fileName} Moved Succesfully")

}
}
```

My rest controller will pass the jobName along the getMapping to invoke this specific route inPath , outPath and File Names

```
@Resource(name=RouteProperties)
private Prosperties props;

@GetMapping("/runJob/{jobToInvoke}")
public String runJob (@PathVariable final String jobToInvoke){
String inPath=props.getProperty("inPath"+jobToInvoke)
String outPath=props.getProperty("outPath"+jobToInvoke)
String fileName=props.getProperty("fileName"+jobToInvoke)

String jobStatus = ProducerTemplate.withHeader("inPath",inPath)
                   .   
                   .
                   .to(??)
                   .request(String.class)
}
```

I need help to use Producer Template to pass the properties using to ?
I tried some search on the google, but there is an example available in youtube ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjMgFcPyBwM&t=145s)) , But in that Video it is calling uri , (Direct:sendMessage) and from in the route also has that.
How to handle in this scenario ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A route beginning with a [`direct:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/direct-component.html) endpoint can be invoked programmatically from Java code. In the route, the [`pollEnrich`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/pollEnrich-eip.html) component invokes a consumer endpoint to read a file and replace the exchange message body with the file contents.

```java
from("direct:start")
    .pollEnrich().simple("file:/tmp?fileName=${header.inPath}")
    .toD("file:/tmp?fileName=${header.outPath}")
    .setBody().simple("File - ${header.inPath} Moved Successfully");
```

To invoke the route from Java code:

```java
String jobStatus = producerTemplate.withHeader("inPath", inPath)
    .withHeader("outPath", outPath)
    .to("direct:start")
    .request(String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. Will try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if these dynamic file URIs in `from` work, but at least the [Camel File documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/file-component.html) states

> Also, the starting directory must not contain dynamic expressions with
> ${ } placeholders. Again use the fileName option to specify the
> dynamic part of the filename.

So the docs are suggesting to change

```
from("file:tmp/${header.inPath}")
```

into

```
from("file:tmp?fileName=${header.inPath}")
```

The `fileName` option can be a relative path (not just a filename).

If that change works for you, your question becomes obsolete because the route URI is no more dynamic.

```
.withHeader("inPath",inPath)
.to("file:tmp")
```

Comment: Will try the same. Thanks for the information.